# my code fails in one test case. am i doing wrong?

Tags: c

Create a code that allows people to learn about exponents.
The task is to write a code which takes an integer number as an input and returns the values ranging from that of 2(two) raised to power 0(zero) to 2(two) raised to power n(the number specified in input).

**Input**

Input contains the number 'n' for which all the values are returned from power of 2 from 0 to n.

**Output**

Output contains the values ranging from 2(two) raised to power 0(zero) to 2(two) raised to power n(input) separated by a comma.

**Constraints**

-1000 ≤ n ≤ 1000

**Sample Input**

5

**Sample Output**

1,2,4,8,16,32

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
   int n;double p=1;
   scanf("%d",&n);
   if(n>0){
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++,p*=2)
          printf("%.0lf,",p);
      printf("%.0lf",p);
   }
   else if(n==0) 
       printf("1");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the point of doing a question like this on HackerRank, etc, is to figure it out yourself?

Comment: For what input does it fail? What is the actual and expected output? Have you tried stepping through the code, line by line while monitoring variables and their values, in a debugger?

Comment: And the output you are getting is ?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Is the test case ot fails related to negative "n"? In that case, you need to use float values and instead of looping up loop down and instead of multiplying divide. I doubt however that n<-32 and n >32 can easily be handled.

Comment: What value does your code print for n = 999?  For n = -999?  Why didn't you take care of these extreme cases?  I'm also not clear how your description maps to the example input and output.  You state "returns the values ranging from that of 2(two) raised to power 0(zero) to 2(two) raised to power n(the number specified in input)" but the output appears to be 2 to the power of _x_ for _x_ in the range 0 to n.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - n=positive extreme cases works fine.But not sure about output format of negative cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative cases not handled

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
     int n,p=1;
     scanf("%d",&n);
     if(n>0){
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++,p*=2)
            printf("%d,",p);
        printf("%d",p);
     }
     else if(n==0) printf("1");
     else{
        for(int i=n;i<0;i--,p*=2)
            printf("-%d,",p);
        printf("-%d",p);
        }
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take care of negative values of 'n'.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer. You should elaborate, otherwise no upvotes.

Comment: can i guess hackerrank?

Answer (score 0):

For N<0, the format specifier should allow decimal points since all the numbers will be between 0 and 1. So for N<0, use double as the data type.
For N>0, use long long data type since all the numbers will be whole integers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int 
main(void)
{
   int n;
   double p=1.0;
   long long llp = 1;

   scanf("%d",&n);

   if(n>0){
       for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
          printf("%lld",llp);
          if( i<n) printf(",");
          llp*=2;
       }
   } else if(n<0){
        for(int i=n;i<=0;i++){
           printf("%.5lf",p);
           if( i<0) printf(",");
           p*=0.5;
        } 
   }else
       printf("1");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Still one test case fails.Sorry I dont know the failed test case input.

Comment: @Ajith - Need to know the output format for the case n < 0.  Need to know  test case failed.  Need to know what is the expected results supposed to be.

Comment: The challange is at dcoder android app.i dont know about n<0 output format.sample output is given only for n>0.

Comment: Is this from hackerank? If so, there is a way to find out the inputs.

Comment: no it is not from hackerrank.it is from Dcoder Android app.

Comment: @Ajith - The output is from C executable.  However this output is displayed on Android App is beyond the scope.  If the output display is the reason for the test to fail, there isn't much I can do to help.

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void){ 
int n;
double p=1; 
scanf("%d",&n); 
if(n>0){ 
for(int i=0;i<n;i++,p*=2) 
printf("%.0lf,",p); 
printf("%.0lf",p); 
} else if(n==0) printf("1"); 
else {
for (int i=0; i>n; i--, p/=2)
printf("%.0lf,",p); 
printf("%.0lf",p); 
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Still one test case fails.Sorry I dont know the failed test case input.

Comment: That code is unreadable because of the lack of indentation.  As such, it is no help to anyone on SO — what you do elsewhere is your business, but here, you need to write legible code.  Indent as you'd like it to look, making sure you use no tabs at all.  Copy'n'paste the code into the edit box, ignoring the preview.  Make sure it looks correct.  Then select the code and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it.  Now check that it looks correct in the preview too, then submit it.

Comment: The code as posted is also buggy — it doesn't compile.